# How to print multiple sheets with different page numbers in the footer area

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to write VBA code Microsoft Excel to print multiple sheets with different page numbers and verbiage from one Excel worksheet in footer area.

I created a button and added some code but get an error.

This code works.

```
Sub PrintBOL()
    Dim x%
    x% = 1
    For x% = 1 To 3
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .CenterFooter = x% & " of 3"
        End With
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next x%
End Sub
```

When adding verbiage to the page numbers, this is where it errors out:

```
Sub PrintBOL()
    Dim x%
    x% = 1
    For x% = 1 To 3
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            If x% = 1 Then
                result = .CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Company Copy" & ActiveSheet.PrintOut
            Else
                If x% = 2 Then
                    result = .CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Customer Copy" & ActiveSheet.PrintOut
                Else
                    If x% = 3 Then
                        result = .CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Carrier Copy" & ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        End With
    Next x%
End Sub
```

Expect 3 pages to print, with

```
1 of 3 Company Copy
1 of 3 Customer Copy
1 of 3 Carrier Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub PrintBOL()
    Dim x%
    x% = 1
    For x% = 1 To 3
        If x% = 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Company Copy"
        ElseIf x% = 2 Then
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Customer Copy"
        ElseIf x% = 3 Then
            ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Carrier Copy"
        End If
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next x%
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome! If you like my answer, please mark it as solution. Thank you.

Comment: While this does solve the OP's problem you may also want to explain why/how it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to have the x% = 1 line there. When you write For x% = 1 to 3 the computer initializes it as 1. 
It also seems to me that you don't need the "If... else" statements at all. x% is already incrementing from 1 to 3 in your For loop. If you're trying to get it to put the number 1 on sheet 1, your problem is:

```
With Activesheet.PageSetup
```

That should be

```
With Activeworkbook.Sheets(x%).PageSetup
```

That way you'll always be focusing on sheet 1 through 3, because it's inside your For loop. Lastly, this line is working against you:

```
result = .CenterFooter = x% & " of 3" & "   Company Copy" & ActiveSheet.PrintOut
```

This is likely the part that's returning an error. When you write it like that, you're storing page parameters (right side of the + sign) to an un-dim'ed variable. Even if you were to Dim result as object you don't tell the computer to do anything with result later, so it wouldn't get you the page stuff at the bottom. With already tells the computer to use whatever object you put after that word.

To switch the verbiage, you could cycle your counter through an array with the proper terms in it.

From what you've told us in your initial question and your follow up comment, I think your final code should look like this:

```
Dim x%
Dim ppl as string
ppl = Array("Company", "Customer", "Carrier")
For x% = 1 To 3
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterFooter = x% & " of " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count & "   " & ppl(x%-1) & " Copy"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Next x%
```

Keep in mind that arrays start with 0, so the x%-1 on your counter keeps everything lined up.

Comment: Jake. Thank you for the reply - I need different verbiage for each page.  Page 1 of 3 Company Copy.  Page 2 of 3 Customer Copy.  Page 3 of 3 Trucking Copy.  I have one worksheet that I want to print 3x with different page numbers and verbiage, hope this makes sense....

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. See my edits to my first comment.